# How to predict cancer-related proteins in Protein-Protein Interaction networks

Tags: bioinformatics, protein-interaction

Protein-Protein Interaction networks are known. It's an undirected graph. Each row of the networks is like this (Protein 2 - Protein 6), and It represents the interaction between Protein 2 and Protein 6.

```
networks:
Protein 2 - Protein 6
Protein 4 - Protein 5
Protein 6 - Protein 5
Protein 5 - Protein 7
...
```

In this networks, It is known that some of proteins are cancer-related proteins, some are nonCancer-related proteins,

```
The known proteins:
Protein 4,Cancer
Protein 6,nonCancer
Protein 7,nonCancer
Protein 10,Cancer
...
```

But the vast majority of proteins is unknown whether is cancer-related protein or noncancer-related protein. How to use these known cancer-related proteins and nonCancer-related proteins to predict the protein whether is or not a cancer-related protein.

I do not know how to solve this problem. I need your help. Thank you very much.